# Python class has unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, class, eof

I have to build a class that will be used in another python file

so far my class reads like so:

```
import csv

class HWReader():
    
    def __init__(self, load_data):
        
        self.load_data = open(load_data, 'r')
        self.filter = " "
        self.threshold = 0
        self.logic = " "
        self.specific = " "
        self.reader = " "
    
    def read_file(self):
        self.reader = csv.DictReader(self.load_data, delimiter = ',')
        return self.reader
        

    def get_saps(self, record_name):
        
        search_for = [record_name]
        
        for row in self.reader:
            if row[0] in search_for:
                print(row['RecordID'], row['SAPS-I'])
```

whenever I try to test the code on the testing file the error I get back is this:

```
File "c:\Users\natv\Documents\LEARNING PROGRAMMING\example4\example4.py", line 29

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I tried just using an example code without the for loop and I still get the same error.

```
import csv

class HWReader():
    
    def __init__(self, load_data):
        
        self.load_data = load_data
        self.filter = " "
        self.threshold = 0
        self.logic = " "
        self.specific = " "
        self.reader = " "
    
    def read_file(self):
        file = open(self.load_data)
        file2 = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter = ',')
        for row in file2:
            return (row['RecordID'], row['SAPS-I'])
```

I check line 29 and there is nothing written there so I'm confused why there is a syntax error.

I'm a newbie at python and I'm a little confused by this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting.  This code reads just fine when I try reading it.  This specific code is example4.py?  You're sure there's no other code before it or after it?

Comment: nope,  this is the code and when I try to import it into another python file and run the command print(csv_data.get_saps("132582")) it says the error.

Comment: @FrankYellin it works now, I had to save the file and then run it and it worked. I guess sometimes turning something on and off again really does work.